# can't import alert library to my javafx application code

Tags: java, javafx-8

Hi all, I am trying to build a desktop application using javaFx, everything works fine until i start thinking about using Dialogs.
I but this piece of code to make a simple Alert but it doesnt work because i can't import Dialog library and ask me to make a class with its the name

My *java* version is ***"1.8.0_73"***

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setTitle("Delete ?");
alert.setHeaderText("Item Deleted");
alert.setContentText("sorry there was a problem!");
alert.showAndWait();
```

thanks a million

Comment: What IDE are you using? (Eclipse? IntelliJ? Netbeans?). The most probable thing is your JDK version is not the same as your JRE version, but checking this would depend on the IDE.

Comment: I am using Netbeans, So how can I check the JDK and JRE version in my IDE

Comment: I'm not using NetBeans, so maybe someone with more experience could help, but [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk8.html) is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using Netbeans, try to update it to build 8.1 . I had the same problem and I fixed it